# Filebeat : Split the multiline json(array of json object) from message field to separate fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I need to use filebeat to push my json data into elastic search, but I'm having trouble decoding my json fields into separate fields extracted from the message field.

Filebeat version : 7.16.2

Filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - /logs/*.json
  multiline.pattern: '^{'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match:  after

processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: "2"
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: false

output.elasticsearch:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

Json Input :

```
{
  "Source": [
    {
      "date": "28-09-2021",
      "language": " C++",
      "comment": 11,
      "code": 150325
    },
    {
      "date": "28-09-2021",
      "language": " C++",
      "comment": 11,
      "code": 106026
    }
  ]
}
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**
separate fields

```
_source: {
@timestamp: "2022-01-12T09:12:36.904Z",
"date": "28-09-2021",
 "language": " C++",
 "comment": 11,
  "code": 106026
input: {
type: "log"
},
```

Please suggest to decode the multiline json in filebeat?